# How do I set a specified image as my desktop background (Windows 10) in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program to set an image, in the same directory as the program, as my desktop background.

The image is a screenshot I take beforehand. This is what I have so far:

```
import time as t
import pyautogui
import ctypes

# screenshot
myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
myScreenshot.save(r'bg.bmp')

# wait a little
t.sleep(1)

# set image as background
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20 
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, r"bg.bmp" , 0)
```

Running the program sets my background as a black screen, but the screenshot is in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

A few changes:

- When setting the background image, use the full file path
- Use `SystemParametersInfoW` instead of `....A`
- Set the last parameter to 3 so the affect is immediate and retained after reboot

Here is the updated code:

```
import time as t
import pyautogui
import ctypes

# screenshot
pyautogui.screenshot(r'c:\tmp\bg.bmp')

# wait a little
t.sleep(1)

# set image as background
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20 
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, r"c:\tmp\bg.bmp", 3)
```

Here is the C# version:
https://code.4noobz.net/set-the-wallpaper-by-code/

Comment: This, uh, doesn't work. Would it make any difference if I'm on a 32 bit machine?

Comment: Odd. I just retested and it works for me. I'm on Win10 64bit.Enterprise.